# Drawer layout над action bar

Tags: android, android-layout, drawerlayout

Как сделать чтобы drawerlayout  был поверх экшнбар. Сейчас код такой

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lv_navigation_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Ставил внутрь и под дроуер не получается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Главным элементом сделайте DrawerLayout.

2) Дайте ему параметр

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

3) Toolbar поместите внутрь FrameLayout, коий внутри DrawerLayout.

4) ???

5) Profit!

Comment: Прекрасно, большое спасибо

Comment: у меня сейчас он чуть больше половины экрана выходит, 
как я могу сделать как google play, 
чтобы оставалось только маленькая полоса

Comment: Судя по всему, вы про его ширину. Задайте нужную в xml или в коде. Сейчас она у вас 240dp.

Comment: я уже весь интернет перерыл и два дня, 
подскажите, как я могу сделать сдвигающие два таба под этим туларом, 
надо сделать, как в youtube клиенте, 
все, что смог сделать, уже по-всякому, как можно подставить такую же анимацию и боковое меню используя стандартную тему с actionBar, на данный момент у меня тема без actionbar или как подставить два таба, которые можно менять свайпом, на этот же тулбар, 
когда использую getSupportActionBar, чтобы под ним поместить табы, 
он возвращает null и потому далее с ним бесполезно работать,
уже очень запарился!

Comment: @eldqs, тут ответил [http://hashcode.ru/questions/384942/android-tab-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5-action-bar]