# Tab ниже action bar

Tags: actionbar, android

пытаюсь добавить tabs,
он либо выходит, но поверх action bar, либо вообще не выходит, если я перемещаю таб ниже:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorAccent"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
             />

        <TabHost
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/tabHost"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="29dp"></TabWidget>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tab1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
                        <fragment
                            android:name="com.example.eldos.callreport.Fragment1"
                            android:id="@+id/frag1"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            tools:layout="@layout/fragment1"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tab2"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

                </FrameLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </TabHost>

    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Как я могу его поместить ниже?

Пытаюсь сделать sliding tab, скачал сэмпл, но там совсем непонятно, или это старый сэмпл. Сделал, как там, все точно так же, но табы даже не появились, они там применяют, скорее всего, старый метод. Может быть, есть уже готовый способ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по комменту [к ответу этого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/384803/android-drawer-layout-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4-action-bar), вы получаете **null** при вызове

> getSupportActionBar();

Моё предположение - у вас Toolbar не назначен ActionBar-ом. Делается это так:

в onCreate() активити находим Toolbar и...

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

После этого должны работать все фишки с табами, т.к. **getSupportActionBar();** больше не будет возвращать **null**.

Comment: да так и делаю, сейчас не применяю tabhost, 

 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        final android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

//        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);

Comment: setSupportActionBar(toolbar); final android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar(); // actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS); actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);       
 for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by the adapter. Also
            // specify this Activity object, which implements the TabListener interface, as the

Comment: выводит ошибку на 
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab tab = actionBar.newTab();

такая ошибка
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.eldos.callreport/com.example.eldos.callreport.MainActivity2}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Tabs are not supported in toolbar action bars
не поддерживается данный метод newTab()

Comment: Хз. Табы не юзал.